# How to Apply styled using Renderer2 to a child node of ElementRef -> nativeElement in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular5, elementref, angular-renderer2

Suppose I have the following Angular Template:

```
<p class="margin0 text-overflow table-cell" #ParentP>
  <span id="managerDisplayName" #FirstSpan class="bold" title="{{ someBinding 1}}">{{ someBinding2 }}</span>
  <span id="regionName" #SecondSpan class="bold regionName" title="{{ someBinding3 }}"> {{ someBinding4 }}</span> 
  <span class="service-level-icon">
    <b placement="bottom" #IconHolder triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" container="body" *ngIf=" someCondition1 " popoverTitle="" [ngbPopover]="servicelevelcontent"><i class="somecon"></i></b>                                        
  </span>
</p>
```

This section of code is being generated multiple times using `*ngFor`.

I want to dynamically change the left alignment of the `<b>` tag by calculating the width of the first and second `<span>`.

I already tried using `[style.left.px]="FirstSpan.offsetWidth + SecondSpan.offsetWidth + 3"`, but this throws the `Expression Changed after Checked` error.

I then thought of trying out using `QueryList<ElementRef>` but I am facing the problem that the icon is present only in some of the cases and hence, I am not able to add style to the `<b>` by using the `children` property of the `ElementRef` as `Renderer2` is throwing error stating unable to find `style` property.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: if you add your code in stackblitz it's easy to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with `[style.left.px]` & use `@viewChildren` for selecting those elements. Update your view code to:

```
<p class="margin0 text-overflow table-cell" #ParentP>
  <span id="managerDisplayName" #FirstSpan class="bold" title="{{ someBinding 1}}">{{ someBinding2 }}</span>
  <span id="regionName" #SecondSpan class="bold regionName" title="{{ someBinding3 }}"> {{ someBinding4 }}</span> 
  <span class="service-level-icon">
    <b placement="bottom" #IconHolder [style.left.px]="updatedLeftStyle" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" container="body" *ngIf=" someCondition1 " popoverTitle="" [ngbPopover]="servicelevelcontent"><i class="somecon"></i></b>                                        
  </span>
</p>
```

Then in component class code make sure you import `ChangeDetectorRef` :

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

This's for updating value of context variable after ViewInit. Now following changes in class:

```
@ViewChildren('FirstSpan,SecondSpan') spans:QueryList<ElementRef>;

constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.debug(this.spans); 
    let eleArr: any = this.spans.toArray();
    this.updatedLeftStyle = eleArr[0].nativeElement.offsetWidth + eleArr[1].nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

[**Demo Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqkj4f)

Comment: Thank you for your working demo.
This fix is working for me!!